# How do I remove a trailing comma from a while loop?

Tags: python, loops

I'm trying to write code for a class where there are 50 numbers, each in rows of 10 with commas separating each number but with no comma at the end of the row.
Currently from my code I'm getting an output of the first block below but I need it to not have the comma after 19, 39, 59, 79, and 99. Could anyone help me? This is python.

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19,
21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39,
41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59,
61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79,
81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99,
```

```
num=1
while num < 100:
  num2 = 10
  while num2 > 0:
    print(num, end=", ")
    num2 = num2 - 1
    num = num + 2
  print ()
```

Comment: Where are you getting this data from?

Comment: Store each row as an array of strings and use `join()` then print the result.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't print a comma after the last element of each line

```
num=1
while num < 100:
  num2 = 10
  while num2 > 1:
    print(num, end=", ")
    num2 = num2 - 1
    num = num + 2
  print(num)
  num = num + 2
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy approach would be to store each line in a `list` and then print the list items joined by `,`  - before that map the integer values to `str` (or cast the values to str before/while appending to the list).

```
num=1
while num < 100:
    out = []
    num2 = 10
    while num2 > 0:
        out.append(num)
        num2 = num2 - 1
        num = num + 2
    print(", ".join(map(str, out)))
```

Output:

```
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19
21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39
41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59
61, 63, 65, 67, 69, 71, 73, 75, 77, 79
81, 83, 85, 87, 89, 91, 93, 95, 97, 99
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion :

```py
a = [str(x) for x in list(range(1,100,2))]
print("\n".join([", ".join(a[10*i:10*(i+1)]) for i in range(5)]))
```

[image]